Whats the relation between RC time constant and the GBWP of an opamp?
If I'm not wrong, an opamp circuit's feedback resistor and capacitor dictates the response time of it. So in case we have the control over Rf and Cf we can set the response time.
But in that case, does the gain-bandwidth product(GBWP) of the opamp has to be bigger or smaller than the Rf * Cf product?
I don't get the relation between these two concepts(RC response and GBWP). Is there a way to explain how they are related?

Can you show a schematic (perhaps with an idealized amplifier + the feedback you have in mind)? Depending on a reader's background, they may make different assumptions on how the capacitor is configured and the dominant poles of the system (e.g. I come from a VLSI+biosignals background, so I assume a dominant output pole to small-signal ground as my first guess, but that is not necessarily true for every reader)

If you're operating in the region where the amplifier has plenty of open-loop gain, you might be able to ignore the GBW product.  Otherwise, you will have to analyze the transfer function including the open-loop response of the amplifier.  It all depends on your feedback network and your system requirements.
